# The CSS of my website looks different on localhost and on Amazon AWS servers

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, fonts

I've deployed my website to Amazon AWS server, but CSS styles looks differently -- the font is bigger and bolder than on the localhost, the same about buttons.

Did you have similar issue? There are loaded the same files, fonts are loaded from Google.

Thanks

Comment: check the page zoom. maybe it's giving you this.

Comment: Page zoom? What's that?

Comment: if you press `ctrl+` several times you page becomes bigger. make sure that both pages are 100%... it's just a guess )

Comment: `ctrl` + `0` will generally make it 100% in most of the browsers... as far as I know. Do you have this issue in all of the browsers?

Comment: I am just testing it... for example each button is wider about 2px, fonts are bolder. This is really weird.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was in used fonts - as I loaded them from Google, the link was like **http://...** and the font was not loaded.

After changing the protocol to **https://** everything is working well.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.